# Angular Material Tree - Nodes are not collapsed initially

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to use the Angular Material Tree component in my Angular application, but I'm having an issue with the initial state of the tree nodes. Despite calling the collapse method on each node in the OnInit lifecycle hook, the tree nodes are not collapsed initially when the page loads.

I've created a minimal, reproducible example to demonstrate this issue:

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NestedTreeControl } from '@angular/cdk/tree';
import { MatTreeNestedDataSource } from '@angular/material/tree';

interface Category {
  name: string;
  children?: Category[];
}

const TREE_DATA: Category[] = [
  {
    name: 'Fruit',
    children: [
      {name: 'Apple'},
      {name: 'Banana'},
      {name: 'Fruit loops'},
    ]
  }, {
    name: 'Vegetables',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'Green',
        children: [
          {name: 'Broccoli'},
          {name: 'Brussels sprouts'},
        ]
      }, {
        name: 'Orange',
        children: [
          {name: 'Pumpkins'},
          {name: 'Carrots'},
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  treeControl = new NestedTreeControl<Category>(node => node.children);
  dataSource = new MatTreeNestedDataSource<Category>();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource.data = TREE_DATA;
    this.dataSource.data.forEach(node => {
      this.treeControl.collapse(node);
    });
  }

  hasChild = (_: number, node: Category) => !!node.children && node.children.length > 0;
}
```

app.component.html

```
<mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl">
  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node">
    <li>
      <div>{{node.name}}</div>
    </li>
  </mat-tree-node>

  <mat-nested-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChild">
    <li>
      <div class="mat-tree-node">
        <button mat-icon-button [attr.aria-label]="'toggle ' + node.name" matTreeNodeToggle>
          <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
            {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
          </mat-icon>
        </button>
        {{node.name}}
      </div>
      <ul [class.example-tree-invisible]="!treeControl.isExpanded(node)">
        <ng-container matTreeNodeOutlet></ng-container>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </mat-nested-tree-node>
</mat-tree>
```

As you can see in this example, the collapse method is called on each node after setting the data for the MatTreeNestedDataSource, but the nodes are still expanded when the page loads.

I have also tried calling the collapse method inside the ngAfterViewInit lifecycle hook to ensure the tree is fully initialized before collapsing the nodes, but it didn't solve the issue.

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I suspect it's because the control doesn't exist yet in the `OnInit` lifecycle hook. Try moving the collapse logic into `ngAfterViewInit`.

Comment: As I have written in the description, I have already tried that.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I missed that, read too quickly. Have you tried adding a timeout to collapse everything a few seconds after the view initializes to make sure the collapse method actually works?